# How to end an application manually in android?

Tags: android, exit

I want to end my app when user presses back key from the home screen. I tried using `System.exit(0)` but it doesn't seem to be working.

What do I have to do to end my application manually?

```
    package com.mahavega.qcdemo;


import com.mahavega.qcdemo.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
     private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());
        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };
        ImageView ad = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ImageView im2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView im3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        ImageView im4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        ImageView im5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        ad.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        im2.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
        im2.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this); 
        im3.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
        im3.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this); 
        im4.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
        im4.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this); 
        im5.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
        im5.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this); 
        ad.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Adds.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,    float velocityY)
        {
            float sensitvity = 50;
            if((e1.getX() - e2.getX()) < sensitvity){
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class));
            }

            return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.exit(0);
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
        }


   }
```

This is my whole code

Comment: How would pressing the back key while on the home screen close your app? For the `onBackPressed()` to work, the Activity it is used in, should be _running_. If you are on the home screen, your app could be _paused_ or _stopped_.

Comment: I mean my app's home screen

Comment: Then you should specify that in the OP eh? ;-) Home screen is, unless otherwise specified, _normally_ used for the Android home screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the version of Android you're running on / building for, you might need to add a little help to your `Activity` to catch the back button. Adding this function provides that help:

```
            @Override 
            public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  { 
                if (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) < 5 
                        && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK 
                        && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) { 
                    onBackPressed(); 
                } 

                return true; 
            }
```

Comment: android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK is depreciated

Comment: You can remove the version check in this case, since all you're doing is terminating the app. If you were doing more, without a version check you would want to make sure your onBackPressed didn't run twice for a single back key event (which would happen on SDK 5 and greater without that check).

Answer (score 2):

In your `Activity` call `finish()`. Reference here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()

Comment: Of course `finish()` is the preferred solution, but in what is probably the op's simple case, System.exit() should work too and as he stated, it isn't... so it would seem his callback is never getting called (and thus it doesn't yet matter yet if he calls `finish()`, `System.exit()`, or `MyNullObject.method()`.

Comment: Sorry, read that question a bit quickly. Your answer makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final void android.os.Process.killProcess(int pid)
```

Simple, works and does what you want. But please note that it is not recommended to exit application explicitly on Android. (Common GUI application just calls finish() on the top most Activity and lets on OS decision when to exit the application process.)

Answer (score 0):

call moveTaskToBack(true) on your Activity (it exits your app from screen but doesn't destroy it)